# anime.js not targetting elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, anime.js

I am trying to create a mouseover triggered animation for each element of a single class and am having issues targeting the relative class instance individually. The only thing that I can get to work is using the whole class in itself as the target as seen below.

```
$('.skillList div').mouseover(() => {
        anime({
            targets: '.skillList div',
            translateX: 2000,
            easing: 'easeOutElastic(1, .6)',
            duration: 2000
        });
})
```

However, the code above results in an animation of each and every element (div) with parent of .skillList. What I'm looking to do is more specific to each element (div). I have tried using $(this) as a target via the multiple approaches shown below...

```
targets: '$(this)'
```

```
targets: $(this)
```

```
targets: [$(this)]
```

```
targets: '[$(this)]'
```

```
targets: ['$(this)']
```

```
targets: 'this'
```

```
targets: this
```

...to which I was surprised, had no effect.

I did a little bit of debugging with the console and made sure that the mouseover function was not to blame.

```
console.log("hovered");
```

^^ Showed that each element had it's own mouseover function.

I also was curious if maybe "this" was returning an element that was compatible with animation, which made things even more confusing. After I console logged "$(this)" I noticed that it returned a nested object where its root contained properties "0: Window, length: 1", which I have never seen before. Here is an image of that...
[image]

All that being said, I am getting no errors when targeting "this" in any of the listed attempts. So I am doubtful that "this" is not capable of .anime(), however, I do know that "this" (which should be the mouseover element) is not being targetted.

Furthermore, I also tried adding a temp class to the mouseover element so I could target it by class name as shown below...

```
$('.skillList div').mouseover(() => {
    $(this).addClass('temp');
    
        anime({
            targets: '.temp',
            translateX: 2000,
            easing: 'easeOutElastic(1, .6)',
            duration: 2000
        });
})
```

...which proved useless...

Finally, I took it a step further to add a class to each of the div elements called skill so I could directly target the div's rather than through its parent .skillList.

```
<div class="skillList">
    <div class="skill">&lthtml&gt</div>
    <div class="skill">.css {}</div>
    <div class="skill">javascript()</div>
    <div class="skill">$php</div>
    <div class="skill">def python():</div>
</div>
```

```
$('.skill').mouseover(() => {
    $(this).addClass('temp');
    
        anime({
            targets: '.temp',
            translateX: 2000,
            easing: 'easeOutElastic(1, .6)',
            duration: 2000
        });
})
```

Note, that I also tried all of the above attempts with the new mouseover element (".skill"). Goes without saying, none of these attempts worked and I'm very confused on what to use as my animejs target. One solution I'm almost sure would work would be giving each element of .skillList a unique ID and making an anime function for each and every element. However, I would like to avoid redundancy and I'm sure you would all understand that.

Thank you in advance for your time, and I apologize for such a long post!
Cheers :)

Comment: To distinguish each div from any other div you have to get some identifier class. Like each div is having one extra class which is different and use that for animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over your items and attach an event to them all individually:

```js
let skills = document.querySelectorAll('.skillList div');

skills.forEach(skill=>{
  
  skill.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
   
      anime({
          targets: skill,
          translateX: 50,
          easing: 'easeOutElastic(1, .6)',
          duration: 2000
       });

  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js" integrity="sha512-z4OUqw38qNLpn1libAN9BsoDx6nbNFio5lA6CuTp9NlK83b89hgyCVq+N5FdBJptINztxn1Z3SaKSKUS5UP60Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div class="skillList">
  <div>skill 1</div>
  <div>skill 2</div>
  <div>skill 3</div>
  <div>skill 4</div>
  <div>skill 5</div>
</div>
```

If you want to this with `jQuery`, you could do it as follow:

```js
let skills = $('.skillList div');

skills.each(function(i) {
  let skill = $(this);
  
  skill.on('mouseover', function() {
      anime({
          targets: skills[i],
          translateX: 50,
          easing: 'easeOutElastic(1, .6)',
          duration: 2000
       });  
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js" integrity="sha512-z4OUqw38qNLpn1libAN9BsoDx6nbNFio5lA6CuTp9NlK83b89hgyCVq+N5FdBJptINztxn1Z3SaKSKUS5UP60Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="skillList">
  <div>skill 1</div>
  <div>skill 2</div>
  <div>skill 3</div>
  <div>skill 4</div>
  <div>skill 5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks champ!